# overide template_name based on some condiitions django clas based views

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a way to specify template name based on some conditions? my bet is  one has to do this in some method, but I don't know which method to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `get_templat_names()` method:

> **get_template_names()**
>
> Returns a list of template names to search for when rendering the template

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names